# Mongoose query - how to create an object for every dataset that is returned

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm query the database and returning an array of objects, which I then want to create an objet for each set of data based on new object properties as well as push each new object into an array. I believe I'm having problems with the promise not resolved, but can't figure out how to resolve it.

The data from the query returns fine, but its when it enter the for-loop, the object isn't created. It goes into the catch statement.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const userTxModel = require('../models/userTx.model');

var RecurringTxObj = (name, user_id, next_amt, next_date, transactions) => {
  this.name = name;
  this.user_id = user_id;
  this.next_amt = next_amt;
  this.next_date = next_date;
  this.transactions = [];
};

router.get('/getRecurringTx', (req, res) => {
  const recurringTxArr = [];
  userTxModel
    .find({ recurring: true })
    .exec()
    .then((recurringTxData) => {
      for (let data of recurringTxData) {
        recurringTxArr.push(
          new RecurringTxObj(
            data.name,
            data.user_id,
            data.amount,
            data.date,
            []
          )
        );
      }
      res.status(200).send(recurringTxArr);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Could not find recurring transactions');
      res.status(500).send('Could not find recurring transactions');
    });
});

router.get('/error', (req, res) => {
  throw new Error('Something went wrong');
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: have you tried `console.log(err)`? What does it say?

Comment: I don't know why I tried everything but that. The problem was with the Constructor being in incorrect es6 format, have now fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the exception you are getting as well as the conole.log of `recurringTxData` before the `for loop`